# how do i add the leaderboard scores to a table

Tags: javascript

So i want to add the scores in the leaderboard to a table but i dont know how to do it.

github:

https://github.com/Eternal-Network/Eternal-hub/tree/master

should i change anything?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>Leaderboard</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Eternal Network">
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="randomize()">Randomize</button>
    <a href="./submit.html">Submit your Score!</a>
    <div id="leaderboard" class="container">
        <!-- scores will be inserted by the script here -->
    </div>
    <script>

        let scores = [
    {name: "Player 1", score: 300},
    {name: "Player 2", score: 370},
    {name: "Player 3", score: 500},
    {name: "Player 4", score: 430},
    {name: "Player 5", score: 340},
];

function updateLeaderboardView() {
    let leaderboard = document.getElementById("leaderboard");
    leaderboard.innerHTML = "";

    scores.sort(function(a, b){ return b.score - a.score  });
    let elements = []; // we'll need created elements to update colors later on
    // create elements for each player
    for(let i=0; i<scores.length; i++) {
        let name = document.createElement("div");
        let score = document.createElement("div");
        name.classList.add("name");
        score.classList.add("score");
        name.innerText = scores[i].name;
        score.innerText = scores[i].score;

        let scoreRow = document.createElement("div");
        scoreRow.classList.add("row");
        scoreRow.appendChild(name);
        scoreRow.appendChild(score);
        leaderboard.appendChild(scoreRow);

        elements.push(scoreRow);

    }

    let colors = ["gold", "silver", "#cd7f32"];
    for(let i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        elements[i].style.color = colors[i];
    }
}

updateLeaderboardView();
function randomize() {
    for(var i=0; i<scores.length; i++) {
        scores[i].score = Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 - 300 + 1)) + 300;
    }
    // when your data changes, call updateLeaderboardView
    updateLeaderboardView();
}
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

I've tried using javascript to add the scores but i don't know how to add the scores to a table

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display the leaderboard scores in a table by creating an HTML table structure and filling it with the scores.

Replace the :

```
<table id="leaderboard">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- scores will be inserted by the script here -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Update your updateLeaderboardView function:

```
function updateLeaderboardView() {
    let leaderboard = document.getElementById("leaderboard").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    leaderboard.innerHTML = "";

    scores.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.score - a.score;
    });

    let colors = ["gold", "silver", "#cd7f32"];

    for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        let rank = document.createElement("td");
        let name = document.createElement("td");
        let score = document.createElement("td");
        
        rank.innerText = i + 1; // rank starts from 1
        name.innerText = scores[i].name;
        score.innerText = scores[i].score;

        let scoreRow = document.createElement("tr");
        if (i < 3) { // apply color for top 3 ranks
            scoreRow.style.color = colors[i];
        }

        scoreRow.appendChild(rank);
        scoreRow.appendChild(name);
        scoreRow.appendChild(score);
        leaderboard.appendChild(scoreRow);
    }
}
```